# How to clear the text in the address bar?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a custom new tab page, and I want links to localhost and my router.  It seems if I want to link to one of these it just appends it to the existing text in my address bar, instead of clearing it like it does for http:// links.

```
$('#router').on('click', function() {
    window.open("192.168.1.1");
});
```

This is the address it opens:

file:///C:/Users/brennan/development/new_tab/192.168.1.1

instead of just:

192.168.1.1

Comment: `"http://192.168.1.1"` ?

Comment: Ha!  Now I have the IP address of your router, one sec while I hack into it.. ::connection lost::

Comment: @JasonSperske - IP addresses starting 192.168 are private ones!

Comment: Also an unfinished comment wouldn't trail off automatically with `::connection lost::` (unless I was [dictating](http://youtu.be/XiT_5cr3tYI?t=30s) :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is using relative paths

Try

```
window.open("http://192.168.1.1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `http://` in the front.

```
 $('#router').on('click', function() {
    window.open("http://192.168.1.1");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try `window.open("http://192.168.1.1")`. Because otherwise code reacts as if you are looking for a local file named 192.168.1.1